# Inquiry about applying stationary action to field lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I am reading David Tong's [lecture notes on quantum field theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html). There is a part where he says:
\begin{align} 
\delta S & = \int d^4x \left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_a}\delta \phi_a + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta (\partial _{\mu}\phi _a)\right]\\
&= \int d^4x \left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_a} - \partial_{\mu} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\right)\right]\delta \phi _a + \partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta \phi_a\right)\tag{1.5}\end{align}

Then, he says that the last term is a total derivative and vanishes for any $\delta \phi _a(x,t)$ and that, requiring $\delta S$ = 0, yields the Euler-Lagrange equations.

My questions are

1. how does he get to the second line?
2. Why does the last term vanish as I quoted he said above.
3. I don't see how this gives us the Euler Lagrange equations. What happens to the happens do the differential $\delta \phi _a$?

Comment: Hint: Integration by parts with appropriate boundary conditions, plus the fact that $\delta \phi_a$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

> My questions are
>
> 1. how does he get to the second line?

Integration by parts.

> 2. Why does the last term vanish as I quoted he said above.

Presumably because his $\delta \phi$ vanishes at the boundary.

> 3. I don't see how this gives us the Euler Lagrange equations. What happens to the ... differential $\delta \phi _a$?

The variation is arbitrary so the term multiplying it has to be identically zero.

This is just like the usual derivation of the Lagrangian equation of motion in classical mechanics, except he is working with fields as the variables instead of positions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for 1.  :**

\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta \phi_a\right)=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta (\partial _{\mu}\phi _a)+\partial_{\mu} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\right)\delta \phi _a
\tag{Fr-01}\label{Fr-01}
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

**Hint for 2. :**

From the 4-dimensional version of the $^{\prime\prime}$divergence theorem$^{\prime\prime}$

\begin{equation}
\iiiint\limits_{\textbf{spacetime}}\!\!\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta \phi_a\right)\mathrm d^4x \boldsymbol{=}\overbrace{\iiiint\limits_{\boldsymbol \Sigma}\!\!\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta \phi_a\right)\mathrm d\Sigma _\mu}^{0}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{Fr-02}\label{Fr-02} 
\end{equation}
where $\:\boldsymbol \Sigma\:$ is an hypersurface in the 4-dimensional spacetime with its space part extending to infinity and the time part between initial and final time moments $\:t_1,t_2\:$ respectively. Also, $\:\mathrm d\Sigma _\mu\:$ is the $^{\prime\prime}$pseudonormal$^{\prime\prime}$ to $\:\boldsymbol \Sigma\:$ infinitesimal 4-vector. The middle term in above equation is the $^{\prime\prime}$flux$^{\prime\prime}$ through $\:\boldsymbol \Sigma\:$ of the 4-vector function
\begin{equation}
\mathsf A^\mu\boldsymbol{=}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\delta \phi_a
\tag{Fr-03}\label{Fr-03} 
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

**Hint for 3. :**

Since we must have

\begin{equation}
\delta S \boldsymbol{=}\iiiint\limits_{\textbf{spacetime}} d^4x \left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_a} - \partial_{\mu} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu} \phi _a)}\right)\right]\delta \phi _a\boldsymbol{=}0
\tag{Fr-04}\label{Fr-04} 
\end{equation}
for arbitrary  $\:\delta \phi _a\:$ the integrand must be identically 0.